# How to search an element in a property file?

Tags: java, file, search

The requirement is:
Invoice number will be passed from the XSLT, based on the invoice number I must increment the counter corresponding to that invoice number.

Example: `invoice=1020` is passed from XSLT, I must read that invoice and search in a file whether it is present or not. If yes, increment counter (`count=prev_count+1`).
If not, write the invoice number in the file and initialize it to 1.

How to acheive this requirement?

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void LookupInsert( int invoiceNumber)
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        File propertiesfile = new File("Sequence.properties");
        if(propertiesfile.length()==0)
        {
            try{
                propertiesfile.createNewFile();
                properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesfile));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int value=1;
            properties.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(value).toString());
        }

        try {
            propertiesfile.createNewFile();
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesfile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        if(props.get(invoiceNumber)== null)
        {
            int value=1;
            props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(value).toString());
            try {
                properties.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(props.get(invoiceNumber).toString());
            value++;
            props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(value).toString());
            try {
                properties.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    // main() is used for testing
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        LookupInsert(101);
        LookupInsert(101);
        LookupInsert(101);
    }
}
```

But the above code is creating file but its not updating value in the file..

Comment: what kind of file that you need to look int. Is it a excel file (or) text File?

Comment: `count=prev_count+1` is not how you increment a counter.

Comment: @ketser tx :) its count=count+1..

Comment: @PavanKumarK its property file.. This is SAP scenario, so there we are using property file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below is the code that you are looking for..

```
public void LookupInsert(int invoiceNumber)
{
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    //if there is no invoice number in properties file then get(invoiceNumber) will be null
    if(props.get(invoiceNumber)== null)
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(1).toString());
    else
    {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(props.get(invoiceNumber).toString());
        value++;
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(value).toString());
    }
File file =new File("test.properties");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
props.store(fw,"");
fw.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but only invoice number will be passed from XSLT code. I have to search whether the Invoice number is present or not .

Comment: The file should be like==>   invoice_no=count

Comment: Thanks a lot .. please check the above modified code

Comment: Its creating the file but not storing any value into it :(

Comment: Its creating the file and initializing it. But its not getting incremented:(